# How to close netcat server after some data has arrived?

Tags: ipv6, netcat

I am sending **UDP** data over the **WLAN** medium and using **IPv6 Multicast**. I am timing the sending using:

```
time yes|cat /tmp/hello.txt | nc -6 -u -q 1 ff02::1%wlan1 30002
```

the client closes after a second because of `-q 1` I am just sending a simple `hello.txt` which has `Test, Hello` in it.

I an running a server on the other network device as follows:

```
nc -6 -u -l -v ff02::1%wlan0 30002
```

And I receive the data:

```
Test, Hello with netcat
```

but I want it to stop once it has received the `EOF` and then show the `time` parameter.

I have wrapping around this thing for a while but don't seem to understand how can I stop the listening on the server and show the time it took to receive data.

### Note

1. I am using **Link-Local multicast IPv6 addresses** (`ff02::`) and I have an external adapter on my client hence `wlan1`
2. `nc` is the `netcat-openbsd` package not the `nc-traditional` one.

Comment: FYI: When sending to ff02::1 you are sending to a multicast group. You are not using link-local addresses...

Comment: @SanderSteffann sorry I meant multicast. Will change that now.

Comment: Are you trying to make `nc -l` exit after one connection, or are you trying to make `time` show you something other than 0.008?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I would just like to know when did I receive the message. If that requires closing exiting `nc -l` exit and then showing `time`, then yes I want that.